# lightbox em página carregada com ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, carregamento

Boas pessoal... é o seguinte: estou a fazer uma página em php mas de java eu não sei mesmo nada.... usei apenas java que retirei de um exemplo para fazer o carregamento dinamico de paginas e para fazer um lightbox... o problema está quando quero conjugar os 2.... quero o lightbox funcionando dentro de uma página carregada com ajax.... eis o código:

página index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu a").click(function( e ){
      e.preventDefault();
      var href = $( this ).attr('href');
      $("#center_content").load( href +" #center_content");
    });
  });
</script>
```

e no div"center_content" são carregados os conteúdos....
agora na página dos conteudos com o lightbox

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function($){
    var addToAll = false;
    var gallery = false;
    var titlePosition = 'over';
    $(addToAll ? 'img' : 'img.fancybox').each(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      var title = $this.attr('title');
      var src = $this.attr('data-big') || $this.attr('src');
      var a = $('<a href="#" class="fancybox"></a>').attr('href', src).attr('title', title);
      $this.wrap(a);
    });
    if (gallery)
      $('a.fancybox').attr('rel', 'fancyboxgallery');
    $('a.fancybox').fancybox({
      titlePosition: titlePosition
    });
  });
  $.noConflict();
</script>
```

NOTA: nao cosegui colocar as chamadas do script mas elas estão la....
Alguém me consegue dizer o que modificar? porque disto eu nao entendo NADA!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você só pode instanciar um lightbox, após o html dele existir.

```
$("#center_content").load( href +" #center_content", function() {
    //aqui dentro você dispara o lightbox
});
```

http://wbruno.com.br/ajax/usando-lightbox-em-pagina-carregada-ajax/

Cara, além disso, você não deve trazer nenhum javascript na página carregada.

Deixe todo ele disponível no primeiro load e não traga nenhuma tag script via ajax.

Comment: é só colocar o segundo script dentro do primeiro? o que me acontece é que ele nao carrega dentro da index e vai para uma pagina nova com o conteúdo! :/

Comment: agora ja consegui que ele nao abra nova aba, carrega a outra pagina mas o efeito lightbox nao funciona!!!